# Dynamic Header Fields Based on SSRS Grouping in Body

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

I have an SSRS report where, in the background code, I set various fields to a hashtable, and reference them in the header. I run this code in the first row of the grouping, JobNum, shown below.

However, when I run the report, on a number of reports, the code fields change on the last page and cycle forward to the next grouping before the previous one is complete.

I have tried a number of things but can't quite figure out the issue here. Any help would be appreciated!

[image]

[image]